# Plot a dataframe based on specific group/id in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

I have a dataset given as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
               4, 4, 4, 4,
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5],
        'cycle': [1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,
                  1,2, 3,4,5,6,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,
                  1,2, 3, 4,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,7,7,7,7,
                   4, 4, 4,4,4,4,
                   8,8,8,8,8,
                   10,10,10,10,
                   15, 15,15,15,15,15,],
        'Jobs': [123, 18, 69, 65, 120, 11, 52,
                 96, 120,10, 141, 52,6,
                 101,99, 128, 1, 141,
                 141,123, 12, 66,
                 12, 128, 66, 100, 141, 52,],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 15,123, 128, 120, 141,
                 141,123, 128, 66,
                 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such:

[image]

In order to plot the 'cycle' vs 'Salary' for id =1, I have used following codes:

```
plt.plot(df.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle'], df.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Salary'], label = 'id=1')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.show()
```

The plot looks as such:

[image]

However, I wish to plot the 'cycle' vs 'Salary' for all id's in one single plot. The graph need to look as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
ax = df.pivot(index='cycle', columns='id', values='Salary').plot()

# display
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_xlim(left=0)
ax.set_ylabel('Salary')
```

Output:

[image]

##### swapping axes

using [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Salary', y='cycle', hue='id',
             palette='Set1', estimator=None)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way by which I can interchange the axes of 'Salary' and 'cycle' ?

Comment: With a different method, see update